# Can Occam's razor be applied to the razor?

Tags: occams-razor

Occam's razor can be applied if the are various theories that give rise to the same process, observation, situation, phenomenon, etc.

But according to which standards shaves the razor undesired theories off? What kind of stuff is the razor made off? Can one apply Occams's razor to the razor itself?

Comment: "What kind of stuff is the razor made off?" What does it mean?

Comment: @MauroAllegranza Exactly what I write. Litterally. The diiferent kinds of stuff imply different degrees of shavings or shave off only the very long hairs. If the razor is constructed from plastic it will not shave off anything. Which material shoulld be chosen? Shall we apply Occams razor to different choicces? A third razor will not be needed as this is logically the same as a second razor.

Comment: You realize Occam's razor is not a literal razor?

Comment: @armand Then what is it? Dont different kinds of razors exist? Each for its own kind of shaving, dependent on what has to shaven? Physical theories need a different razor as theological ones or criminal ones. What determines which razor you have to use and which blades you have to use? What determines the settings of the razor? Can the razor itself  be shaven?